# Wanting to add storage over garage

Tags: attic, storage, truss

So I have picked up woodworking as a hobby and find myself becoming pressed for space in the garage.  I looked in the attic and this is the layout:  [image: Attic Image]

Is it possible to remove these angled supports and put in another vertical or something to give me better access to lay some plywood out so I can slide boxes towards the front of the garage?  Could I just do it to the left side maybe or could I do it to both sides?  I'm not entirely sure how the structural side of this works so I am trying to find information to help me decide if this is a possibility or not.

Comment: Those are prefab trusses.  You'd need to run it by the truss builder or an engineer how to replace the strength of those elements with something else.   But no, they're not just there to thwart use of the space.

Comment: Do you get snow in the winter?

Comment: The answer is almost always no, you cannot take out the inconvenient angled parts of trusses, and in most garages, unless they were built with a "storage truss" and a floor, they are often specified to have no storage load capacity at all (to make them cost as little as possible.)

Comment: You could add some stringers about 12-16" up the center post to the diagonal members and put plywood over them. It's not an ideal solution, but it wouldn't compromise the structural integrity of your engineer trusses.

Answer (score 4):

The only answer for removal of those angle 2x4s is no, it is not possible at all unless a major reinforcement of the ceiling and roof is done.

The members that make up the roof are set so they work together as a whole, and to remove one part will severely weaken the whole truss that the piece was removed from. Remove one piece from more than one truss, you may, or will have catastrophic failure on your hands.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to talk to an architect/engineer about some sort of "assemble-in-place" truss that would carry the entire roof load, and that you could "sister" to the existing trusses.  Effectively the new field-assembled trusses would replace 100% of the carrying capacity of the built trusses, whose only function would be to "be what the roof is nailed into" so you don't need to remove your roof to nail into your new trusses.

With the new engineered trusses in place, then you can demolish the offending parts of the old trusses.

This sounds expensive :b  You might be better off tearing the roof off the garage, tearing the OSB off the roof, and replacing the trusses with off-the-shelf trusses rated for storage... then re-OSB and re-roof.  Depending on the age of the roof and when it'll be due.